# Making a specific object pause C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am looking at trying to pause something in C++. Specifically a bullet you shoot in a space invaders game. Each time you press the UP key it fires a shot, I have been trying to find a way to pause it for a number of seconds before being able to fire again.

I've tried Sleep(); but it freezes the entire game rather than pauses the ability to press UP again.

Firing code

```
if (CInput::getInstance()->getIfKeyDownEvent(DIK_UP))
    {
        g_pGame->AddSprite(new CMissile(m_fX, m_fY+0.5*m_fH, 0.09, 0.9, 2));


    }
```

Comment: put a `frozen` flag on the object, and perform the move animation only when the flag is off

Answer (score 3):

Try taking the current time and then adding your delay to it. Store that in your shooting object. The next time through your program loop, if the current time is less than the time stored in the object, ignore the UP arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two simple ways to manage this.

When you fire a bullet, take the current system time and add the delay you want to it. If the player attempts to fire again while the current time is less than the variable you set, nothing happens.

Or, when you fire a bullet, set a timer variable to the delay you want. Each update, subtract delta time from the timer. When the timer is <=0, the user can fire.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you want to deal with real time seconds, you need something called delta time. Due to the inconsistency with frame rates, you need a way to measure real time. Typically you do this by counting the amount of time elapsed between frames. Here's an example of this implementation:

[Source](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13008/how-to-get-and-use-delta-time)

```
int timeSinceStart = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);

int oldTimeSinceStart = 0;

while( ... ) // main game loop
{
     int timeSinceStart = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
     int deltaTime = timeSinceStart - oldTimeSinceStart;
     oldTimeSinceStart = timeSinceStart;

     secondsSinceLastShot += deltaTime;
     if (secondsSinceLastShot > shotTimer)
     {
         canShoot = true;
         secondsSinceLastShot = 0;
     }
     if ( // press space or something )
     {
         canShoot = false;
         // shoot
     }
}
```

Note that this uses GLUT's implementation of a timer, but you need to implement that yourself (probably using `clock()`).

> I've tried Sleep(); but it freezes the entire game rather than pauses the ability to press UP again.

Sleeping will freeze the thread, which is not what you want to do. However, `sleep()` is typically used in an implementation that contains delta time, usually `sleep()`ing for the amount of time elapsed between frames. For an example, see [Lazy Foo's SDL tutorials](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson14/)

Ignore the fact that I linked to both OpenGL and SDL links, the principle is the same no matter the graphics library used.